On Visual Studio Code using Robot Framework - can't go to definition that has regular expression
I have a keyword on Robot Framework this is defined like that on def.robot:
Apply My Operation On MY VAR${var:[^ ]+}
    Log        message
         

On test.robot, I have the following code line:
Apply My Operation On MY VAR${MyValue}                     
                  

When I try to go to the definition of the line above - VS code doesn't recognize where's the definition (in contrast to the IDE named RIDE - where there it works).
However, if I change the definition on def.robot to be:
Apply My Operation On MY VAR${var}
    Log        message

Now VS code indeed recognizes the definition.
If it matters, I'm using Robot Framework Language Server extension.
Do you know how can I make VS code recognizes the original definition, just like RIDE recognizes it?

Hello @Tuval4980, the Robot Framework Language Server extension is not recommended since it is no longer maintained. Try using RobotCode extension instead.
